# maximum number of OpenAL sound buffers on iPhone

Tags: iphone, openal

I'm writing a sound library, for the iPhone, that uses OpenAL.  The app generates a unique buffer id for each sound, during startup.  The problem that I'm having is that OpenAL is unable to generate more than 1024 buffer ids.

I would've thought that the total number of buffer ids would've been limited by memory, not by some pre-determined number.  I haven't been able to find any documentation that specifies the maximum number of buffers available to OpenAL on an iOS device.

Can anyone confirm this limit of 1024 buffers?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

The maximum number of buffers on iOS and on OS X is 1024.

The maximum number of sources is 32 on iOS and 256 on OS X.